# Python: How do I plot a signal with color-coded values as background?

Tags: python, matplotlib, signals, overlay, colormap

I am a beginner in Python and matplotlib, extensive search did not yield anything useful, so here goes:

I have aquired `data` (256 samples per seconds) from a device.
Code below will recreate (and plot) the data set.

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set variable
Fs = 256
# Create list with random measurements
np.random.seed(1)
data = [np.random.uniform(-20000, 20000) for i in range(10*Fs)]
#plt.plot(data, color = "black", linewidth = 0.3); plt.show()
```

For `data`, I have calculated several values for every second, i.e. 256 data points. Every second is characterized by a set of these numbers.
Code below will create a data set for 3 of these numbers, called `sig_val`s.

```
# Create lists with random sig_values with length of 1/Fs of measurements
sig_vals1 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
sig_vals2 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
sig_vals3 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
```

**The goal is to have an overlay graph that shows**

1. heatmap-like color-coded information about the `data`'s intervals,
2. overlayed with the original `data`.

[image: https://ibb.co/iZcvWk]

**How do I get a nice plot of color-coded values of `sig_vals` as background of `data`?**

Comment: What is it doing differently from what you want? Is it just that it's not overlaid? You'd accomplish that by not closing in between plots.

Comment: @mauve: not using `plt.close()` between the first `plt.show()` and `plt.plot(data)` will also not yield an overlay.

Also, please note that I want `sig_vals1`to `sig_vals3`as background - the spectrogram was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear how the three signals are related to the data and how the should appear on a plot. I would think that the paragraph about specgram is more confusing than helping (as apparently you don't want to have a specgram plot at all). While it might be clear to you what "sig_vals1 to sig_vals3 as background"  means, it is most certainly not for other readers of the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: You are right, problem description was misleading even after my first edit. I added a (handdrawn) figure that hopefully shows what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could be what you're after. It assumes that both data sets are spreadover the same range of 10 seconds. The signals to colorcode are joined in a 3 by 10 matrix, which can be plotted using `pcolormesh`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set variable
Fs = 256
# Create list with random measurements
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.uniform(-20000, 20000, size=10*Fs)
t = np.linspace(0,10,len(data))

sig_vals1 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=int(len(data)/Fs)) 
sig_vals2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=int(len(data)/Fs))
sig_vals3 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=int(len(data)/Fs))
sig = np.c_[sig_vals1,sig_vals2,sig_vals3].T

T, s = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,10,int(len(data)/Fs)+1),np.arange(4))


plt.pcolormesh(T,s,sig)
plt.yticks(np.arange(.5,3,1), ["Signal{}".format(i+1) for i in range(3)])

ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
ax2.plot(t, data, color = "w", linewidth = 0.3, alpha=0.6)
ax2.margins(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your problem is a scale problem... when you plot your spectrogram the x axis is in range 0-8 second and y axis in range of Fs/2=128, when your data are in rang of [-20000:20000] for the y axis and 2560 in your x axis... so you should scale your data to plot in the same graph.

you can do something like :

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Set variable
Fs = 256
# Create list with random measurements
np.random.seed(1)
data = [np.random.uniform(-20000, 20000) for i in range(10*Fs)]
#plt.plot(data, color = "black", linewidth = 0.3); plt.show()
# Create lists with random sig_values with length of 1/Fs of measurements
sig_vals1 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
sig_vals2 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
sig_vals3 = [np.random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(int(len(data)/Fs))]
```

Here how to plot overlaid :

```
plt.specgram(data, Fs=Fs) #plot spectrogram
t=[float(i)/Fs for i in range(10*Fs)] #create time vector
data2=[((float(i)/40000)+0.5)*Fs/2 for i in data] # scale data between [0:128] to overlay spectrogram
plt.plot(t, data2, color = "black", lw=0.3) # plot scaled data
plt.show()
```

But maybe it's better to create subplot and keep the original data :

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.specgram(data, Fs=Fs)
plt.specgram(data, Fs=Fs)
plt.subplot(212 )
plt.plot(t, data, color = "black", lw=0.3)
plt.show()
```

***EDIT :*** 
use `imshow()` :

```
tot=[sig_vals1, sig_vals2,sig_vals3]
t=[float(i)/Fs for i in range(10*Fs)]
data2=[((float(i)/40000)+0.5)*2 for i in data]
plt.plot(t, data2, color = "black", lw=0.3)
plt.imshow(tot)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved a problem I had not had seen before your answer.

Please note that my main goal is to have an overlay graph that shows

1. heatmap-like color-coded information about the `sig_val`'s intervals
2. overlayed with the original `data`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it does not solve my problem. I still need a way to plot all `sig_vals` as color-coded background, and `data`on top.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, did not understood... Now I saw edit on your post, much better. See edit in my post